# Translate text on the front page with t()

Tags: i18n-l10n

Have a multilingual site with English and French, I have all my static text on my page--front.tpl.php wrapped with a t(), cleaned my cache and refreshed the strings, but still i cant find the strings to translate them.
I'm I doing something wrong here?
example of code on page--front.tpl.php

```
<div class="class-example">
        <p><a href="node/add/poll" class="create-nav-dim cr-nav-bg mb10"><?php print t('Create New content'); ?></a></p>
        <h2 ><?php print t('OR'); ?></h2>
        <p><a href="#" class="example-class"><?php print t('check our content'); ?></a></p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to activate the locale module.

Under "Admin >> Configuration" you find a section regional and language.
Add a new language, and set it as default language; after that, you can use the 'translate interface' to translate the strings wrapped in `t()` for your new language.

Comment: I did that, still cant find the strings to translate them

Comment: And you are sure you have more then 1 language installed?

Comment: yes, have 3 languages installed, the main question is how come I cant find the string in the "translate interface" section?

Comment: Try clearing cache, deinstall and reinstall the locale module.

Comment: still nothing, I disabled and re-enabled the modules, and enabled all sub modules

Comment: Did you set your new language as default?

Comment: Finally got it to work, all I had to do was to switch default language to French then go through the french administration menu to translate interface and there was my string waiting for me. thank you @dimitril for your help.

Answer (score 3):

After you've activated `locale.module`, you need to **switch to another language and view the page in that language** — until you do that, the strings to translate aren't added to the database.